# My Array manipulations are slower than my list manipulations

Tags: python, numpy

I want to plot some random walks. I have heard that numpy arrays are alot faster than lists. But my array manipulations take twice to thirty times as long as my list manipulations. What am i doing wrong?

```
from random import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

t0 = time.time()

rw1 = list()
rw1.append(-1 if random() < 0.5 else 1)
for i in range(1, 10000):
    movement = -1 if random() < 0.5 else 1
    rw1.append(rw1[i-1] + movement)

t1 = time.time()
rw2 = [0]
rw2_array = np.array(rw2, dtype=int)

for i in range(1, 10000):
    movement = -1 if random() < 0.5 else 1
    rw2_array = np.append(rw2_array, rw2_array[i-1] + movement)

t2 = time.time()

rw3 = np.zeros(10000)

for i in range(1, 10000):
    movement = -1 if random() < 0.5 else 1
    rw3[i] = rw3[i-1] + movement

t3 = time.time()
print("time: ", t1-t0, t2-t1, t3-t2)
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to notice any benefit between the two types if you're addressing one element at a time in a loop, it's still going to be slow.  What you're probably hearing people talk about is that numpy arrays are good for vectorized operations - applying a function to the entire array at once - which will be much faster.

Comment: appending into a numpy array is likely your bottleneck. Try allocating the full size of the array and then set elements by index

Comment: ` I have heard that numpy arrays are alot faster than lists.`  That's true only if arrays are used in the right way, and are big enough.  Used iteratively like lists, they are slower, especially if you use the poorly name `np.append`.  There's no shortcut to actually learning to use numpy correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be iterating over numpy arrays.  Instead build the array of movements and then calculate the random walk.  We can build the movements by randomly selecting +1 or -1 for an array of size 10000.  To get the random walk, you can use the cumulative sum method.

```
import numpy as np

movements = np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=10000)
rw = movements.cumsum()
```

The operations take place at the C layer and are significantly faster than operations in native Python.  By iterating over the numpy array, you are taking the integer out of C and creating a Python object for each number.  This process is slow because of the overhead in creating each object.

By using the functions and methods in numpy, you are passing calls to the C layer to do all of the operations there.